# Does X3:Albion Prelude still have a private sector?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

In Terran Conflict, you could get a private sector. (As well as a Headquarters for that sector. You could put the HQ anywhere, but in the private sector seems the best place to put it to me.) Since Albion Prelude is just a plugin/expansion to Terran Conflict, does it still have the private sector and headquarters?

I never quite managed to get both in TC and that's one of the biggies I always wanted to do in TC. Thinking about playing again, but if AP doesn't have both of those, I think I may just go back to my old TC save so I can finally get them. 15 minutes of Googling has turned up nothing on if they exist in Albion Prelude. I'm guessing the fact I can't find a mention of it anywhere means they're not in Albion Prelude, but I thought I'd ask just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The player HQ and Hub are still in the latest X3:AP (make sure you update the patches since the quest is not in 1.0 of AP).  There are also several unknown sectors you can 'claim' in AP, but if you are thinking of the reward sector you get In X3:TC, that sector has since then been claimed by a race.  The total number of unowned sectors in AP is now lower as each race decided to expand a little.

Comment: In 3.0 patch was added mission with reward sector.

Comment: PHQ =/= Hub. One is a space station, the other is a superstructure that can mess with the jumpgate network.

Comment: @kotekzot you are correct

Answer (score 3):

In Albion Prelude 3.0 was added new mission `Breaking Grounds`. As reward for completing this mission you get very own sector.

Source: [Egosoft forum](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=336585)

Comment: just keep in mind this sector is not the same reward sector as TC, but yes it is your own sector.